# Strange NPM error on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, windows-10, build-tools

After setting myself up with the stock `react-native` setup, and beginning to switch to typescript, I went to `yarn install` and I got

```
> yarn install v1.3.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility 

check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > babel-jest@22.0.4" has unmet peer dependency "babel-core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0-0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[1/1] ⢀ weak: Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
[-/1] ⢀ waiting...
[-/1] ⢀ waiting...
[-/1] ⢀ waiting...
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "C:\\Users\\me\\projects\\mycrate\\node_modules\\weak: Command failed.\nExit code: 1\nCommand: node-gyp rebuild\nArguments: \nDirectory: C:\\Users\\me\\projects\\mycrate\\node_modules\\weak\nOutput:\nC:\\Users\\me\\projects\\mycrate\\node_modules\\weak>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node \"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\node-gyp-bin\\\\..\\..\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js\" rebuild )  else (node \"\" rebuild ) \r\ngyp info it worked if it ends with ok\ngyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2\ngyp info using node@9.3.0 | win32 | x64\ngyp info spawn C:\\Python27\\python.EXE\ngyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node_modules\\\\npm\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp\\\\gyp\\\\gyp_main.py',\ngyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',\ngyp info spawn args   '-f',\ngyp info spawn args   'msvs',\ngyp info spawn args   '-G',\ngyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',\ngyp info spawn args   '-I',\ngyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\me\\\\projects\\\\mycrate\\\\node_modules\\\\weak\\\\build\\\\config.gypi',\ngyp info spawn args   '-I',\ngyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node_modules\\\\npm\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp\\\\addon.gypi',\ngyp info spawn args   '-I',\ngyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\me\\\\.node-gyp\\\\9.3.0\\\\include\\\\node\\\\common.gypi',\ngyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',\ngyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',\ngyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\\\Users\\\\me\\\\.node-gyp\\\\9.3.0',\ngyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node_modules\\\\npm\\\\node_modules\\\\node-gyp',\ngyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\me\\\\.node-gyp\\\\9.3.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',\ngyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\\\Users\\\\me\\\\projects\\\\mycrate\\\\node_modules\\\\weak',\ngyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',\ngyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',\ngyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',\ngyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',\ngyp info spawn args   'C:\\\\Users\\\\me\\\\projects\\\\mycrate\\\\node_modules\\\\weak\\\\build',\ngyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]\ngyp info spawn C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\msbuild.exe\ngyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',\ngyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',\ngyp info spawn args   '/nologo',\ngyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]\nBuilding the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the \"/m\" switch.\r\nMSBUILD : error MSB4132: The tools version \"2.0\" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are \"12.0\", \"14.0\", \"4.0\".\r\ngyp ERR! build error \ngyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1\ngyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\lib\\build.js:258:23)\ngyp ERR!Done in 7.68s.
```

The relevant error seems to be:

```
error MSB4132: The tools version \"2.0\" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are \"12.0\", \"14.0\", \"4.0\".\r\ngyp ERR! build error \ngyp ERR! stack Error:
```

Following this down the rabbithole I tried a handful of things:

- Installing the standalone build tools
- Attempting to `npm install` the `windows-build-tools` package with `npm 
  install --production windows-build-tools --global` in an administrative shell
- Attempting to set the version of msvc to use in npm using `npm config set msvs_version 201x --global`. Where `x` is either `3`, `5`, or `7`.

None of this has worked.

I'm at a loss for what to do and "just use a mac or linux machine" isn't an option at the moment.

EDIT:

My package dependencies are:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.51.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^22.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.34",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.51.9",
    "babel-jest": "22.0.4",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "jest": "22.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  },
```

EDIT AGAIN:

I forgot to mention that I did close and reopen the command line for each step.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug with the version of npm you are using.

See this thread:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18380

Try rolling back your version of npm to 5.3

The issue appears to be exclusive to windows with babel packages.